# Unable to open excel using ApachePOI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am creating a new xlsx file and trying to open it with apache-poi

```
 File file = new File("file.xlsx");
 XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

Yet I am getting the following error when trying to execute

```
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file: 'file.xlsx'
```

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace to see where exactly this is reported.

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: Can't open the specified file: 'file.xlsx'`

Maybe you should use the full path to your file inside your filesystem, because it could not find it, or your user has not the permissions to open a file in the current execution filepath, etc.

You can look at the [according section in the Apache POI Busy Developers' Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Files+vs+InputStreams) :

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("MyExcel.xlsx"));
```

AND do you open it with code-like below?

```
// XSSFWorkbook, File
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(new File("file.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);

....

pkg.close();
```

Comment: I tried all of those methods both using a  the full path and not and still get the same  error

Comment: hmm strange! maybe updating your Apache POI to the last version will resolve everything. Try it. Sometimes libs downloads are corrupted. Sometimes bugfixes fixes everything.